# Large size font files not loading in website

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have a website in which I am importing the fonts and font file size is **13mb**. it works fine on local machine but when I update on live server and open the website, it keeps loading and fonts does not apply. The problem which I think is the file size of font is too big so this does not load properly. Here is the code snippet:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'Jameel Noori Nastaleeq';
   src: url('../fonts/JameelNooriNastaleeq.ttf');
 }
```

So is there a way to decrease the font size file or same size load quickly with slow internet connections.

Comment: 13MB? That is like larger than the website itself :-/

Comment: @TheDarkKnight yeah that's why it's creating problem. Any idea to reduce it ?

Comment: Did you try converting it to a WOFF format and using?

Comment: @TheDarkKnight yes I tried it but nothing happened ...

Comment: Would you mind providing me a url to your site?

Comment: Why is the font-size that large? Aren't there alternative fonts to use because a 13mb font will never work! Even if you convert it, you still need to have the ttf file format to make sure that in every browser you font loads. I would recommend: find another alternative font which looks the same!

Comment: @TheDarkKnight sorry for late response. Here is the url. http://www.sultan-ul-arifeen.com/urdu/ ... And the font I am trying to load is in urdu.

Comment: @Rotan075 the file format is in ttf and I have to use this font because it is the requirement of the site and this font suits it well...

Comment: Thank you. Looks like that font is loading without an issue to me... http://i.imgur.com/UZQKCDg.png May it because the font is big in size there might some issues in downloading the font in slow connections

Comment: @TheDarkKnight which connection are you using ? yeah that's the real problem if the connection time is fast then there won't be any issue...

Comment: Mine is an 8 MBpS ADSL. Try this code instead of your font-face `@font-face {
  font-family: 'Jameel Noori Nastaleeq';
  src: url('http://www.fontsaddict.com/fontface/jameel-noori-nastaleeq.ttf');
}`

Comment: subset your font. If your pages only use 5% of the font, derive that 5% - a 13MB web font is not a web font, it's a system font that you're pretending can be used as a web font.